# Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am in the processing of upgrading old iOS5 code to iOS8.

My original code:

```
NSInteger maximumValue = -1;
if (results.count == 1) {
    Answer *result = (Answer*)[results objectAtIndex:0];
    maximumValue =  [result.order integerValue];
}
return maximumValue+1;
}
```

Which returns the error Implicit conversion loses integer precision: *long to int*

If I change it to `NSUInteger` from `NSInteger` I get the error Implicit conversion loses integer precision:

> 'unsigned long' to int'

I've been able to update all of the int's to `NSUInteger`, these two issues are my only two remaining and I am spinning my wheels.

Comment: What kind of object is `result.order`?

Comment: Weird. Try changing all  `NSInteger`s to `int`s and call `intValue` on `result.order`. Is `result.order` an `NSString`?

Comment: These are warnings, not errors.

Comment: If you're working for 64bit `NSUInteger` is an `unsigned long`

Comment: What line is giving the error exactly and what's the return type of the method this is returning from?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem almost certainly is that your method or function (whatever `return` is returning from) has a return type of `int`. It should have a return type of `NSInteger`.